# Use clock() to count program execution time

Tags: c, performance, time

I'm using something like this to count how long does it takes my program from start to finish:

```
int main(){
    clock_t startClock = clock();
    .... // many codes
    clock_t endClock = clock();
    printf("%ld", (endClock - startClock) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

And my question is, since there are multiple process running at the same time, say if for x amount of time my process is in **idle**, durning that time will clock tick within my program?

So basically my concern is, say there's 1000 clock cycle passed by, but my process only uses 500 of them, will I get 500 or 1000 from `(endClock - startClock)`?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to measure CPU time or wall-clock time?

Comment: I want to compare different implementation's performance, so I think CPU time would be more suitable. Any advise?

Comment: Are you on Linux or Windows? Or something else?

Comment: Since you're on Linux, `clock()` will give you CPU-time. This is a good way to measure performance if your application is only single-threaded (provided you don't have other processes that could interfere via cache or Hyperthreading...). However, if it's multi-threaded, using a wall-clock will give more meaningful performance results.

Comment: I'm actually trying to compare the performance between different implementations (using 16/32/64/etc threads). Can I do `startClock=clock()` before threads creation, and `endClock=clock()` after join? Why would wall-clock give more meaningful performance if it's multi-threaded code? Thanks.

Comment: Then you will want to use a wall-clock. Measuring CPU-time on a multi-threaded application isn't very meaningful since there could be load-imbalance and idle threads. For that you will need to use `gettimeofday()`. See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clock` on POSIX measures cpu time, but it usually has extremely poor resolution. Instead, modern programs should use `clock_gettime` with the `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` clock-id. This will give up to nanosecond-resolution results, and usually it's really just about that good.

Comment: YMMV. I just found on the AIX system I use at work, `clock_gettime` has even worse resolution than `clock`. `clock` seems to have a resolution of about 3ms, while `clock_getres` reports 10ms resolution.

Answer (score 11):

This depends on the OS. On Windows, `clock()` measures wall-time. On Linux/Posix, it measures the combined CPU time of all the threads.

If you want wall-time on Linux, you should use `gettimeofday()`.

If you want CPU-time on Windows, you should use `GetProcessTimes()`.

EDIT:

So if you're on Windows, `clock()` ***will*** measure idle time.

On Linux, `clock()` ***will not*** measure idle time.

Comment: In either case, I would not use it; it has very poor resolution. See my answer.

Comment: True, but looking at the comments, the program is multi-threaded, so I'm not sure the OP wants to use CPU-time to measure performance.

Answer (score 1):

As per the definition on the man page (in Linux),

> The clock() function returns an approximation of processor time used
>   by the program.

it will try to be as accurate a possible, but as you say, some time (process switching, for example) is difficult to account to a process, so the numbers will be as accurate as possible, but not perfect.