# How to use nanosleep() in C? What are `tim.tv_sec` and `tim.tv_nsec`?

Tags: c, posix, sleep

What is the use of `tim.tv_sec` and `tim.tv_nsec` in the following?

How can I sleep execution for `500000` microseconds?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
   struct timespec tim, tim2;
   tim.tv_sec = 1;
   tim.tv_nsec = 500;

   if(nanosleep(&tim , &tim2) < 0 )   
   {
      printf("Nano sleep system call failed \n");
      return -1;
   }

   printf("Nano sleep successfull \n");

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Half a second is 500,000,000 nanoseconds, so your code should read:

```
tim.tv_sec  = 0;
tim.tv_nsec = 500000000L;
```

As things stand, you code is sleeping for 1.0000005s (1s + 500ns).

Comment: cool. Just one more question. I am testing this using gettimeofday() twice and getting the difference. I therefore got a difference of half a second. But there was also a very small fraction of a sec, due to cpu processing time assume. How can i calculate this and subtract it from the my sleep time. my time came up as: 0.501033 sec

Comment: @pnizzle: What exactly are you hoping to achieve with that subtraction?

Comment: i am hoping to achieve exactly 0.500000secs. Thanks

Comment: Most timers aren't that finely grained. Especially on a multitasking machine, it is difficult to sleep precisely.

Comment: i have googled a bit and have found a function clock().. What does this do exactly. Does it time cpu usage ?

Comment: @pnizzle: You might consider taking a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477486/use-clock-to-count-program-execution-time

Comment: What does the L after `500000000` do? Is it necessary to have that?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye here is the answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697487/what-does-the-l-at-the-end-of-a-number-do

Comment: for 500,000 microseconds, you can also use usleep(500000), see, https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/usleep.3.html

Answer (score 59):

`tv_nsec` is the sleep time in nanoseconds. 500000us = 500000000ns, so you want:

```
nanosleep((const struct timespec[]){{0, 500000000L}}, NULL);
```

Comment: What is the ´L` at the end of `500000000L`  for?

Comment: This relate to long double. as the second argument of nanosleep() have long double type.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380653/why-do-you-need-to-append-an-l-or-f-after-a-value-assigned-to-a-c-constant

Comment: The type of the second variable of nanosleep structure is `long`. The L is used to convert the number to `long`, cause `int` may be too small to handle the value. Some safety standards (NASA, MISRA) force specifying number type if the number is bigger then 2^16 to avoid buggy code.

Answer (score 12):

500000 microseconds are 500000000 nanoseconds. You only wait for 500 ns = 0.5 µs.

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me ....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>   /* Needed for struct timespec */


int mssleep(long miliseconds)
{
   struct timespec rem;
   struct timespec req= {
       (int)(miliseconds / 1000),     /* secs (Must be Non-Negative) */ 
       (miliseconds % 1000) * 1000000 /* nano (Must be in range of 0 to 999999999) */ 
   };

   return nanosleep(&req , &rem);
}

int main()
{
   int ret = mssleep(2500);
   printf("sleep result %d\n",ret);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: So it's not nsleep(...) but msleep(...) ?

Comment: It's just one more character to spell milliseconds correctly.

Answer (score 8):

I usually use some #define and constants to make the calculation easy:

```
#define NANO_SECOND_MULTIPLIER  1000000  // 1 millisecond = 1,000,000 Nanoseconds
const long INTERVAL_MS = 500 * NANO_SECOND_MULTIPLIER;
```

Hence my code would look like this:

```
timespec sleepValue = {0};

sleepValue.tv_nsec = INTERVAL_MS;
nanosleep(&sleepValue, NULL);
```

Answer (score 4):

**POSIX 7**

First find the function: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nanosleep.html

That contains a link to a [`time.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/time.h.html), which as a header should be where structs are defined:

> The  header shall declare the timespec structure, which shall > include at least the following members:
>
> ```
> time_t  tv_sec    Seconds. 
> long    tv_nsec   Nanoseconds.
> ```

**man 2 nanosleep**

Pseudo-official glibc docs which you should always check for syscalls:

```
struct timespec {
    time_t tv_sec;        /* seconds */
    long   tv_nsec;       /* nanoseconds */
};
```

Answer (score 4):

More correct variant:

```
{
struct timespec delta = {5 /*secs*/, 135 /*nanosecs*/};
while (nanosleep(&delta, &delta));
}
```

Comment: Corect for nanosecs: --> struct timespec delta = {5 /*secs*/, 135*1000000/*nanosecs*/};

Comment: 135*1000 000 -> 135 microsecs ?

Comment: 135 microsecs == 135 000 nanosecs, because second field have nanosec value "tv_nsec"