# How to make a child thread waiting for the main thread

Tags: c, multithreading

I've got 2 threads : one child which detects mouse events, and the other main one which execute the program.

*global variable :*

```
int g_wait = 0;
```

*child thread :*

```
void *mouseEvent2(void *arg) 
{
int fd;
struct input_event ev;
const char* pFile = "/dev/input/event0";

signal(SIGINT, SAMPLE_VGS_HandleSig);
signal(SIGTERM, SAMPLE_VGS_HandleSig);

fd = open(pFile, O_RDONLY);
if (fd == -1) {
    printf("ERROR Opening %s\n", pFile);
    return NULL;
}

while(scroll != -1) {
    read(fd, &ev, sizeof(ev));

    [... Some code with if statement ... ]
    if(...) //left mouse button
        g_wait = !g_wait;

    [need waiting so the thread won't use at 100% a core]
}
close(fd);
(void) arg;
pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

*Main thread :*

```
int main() {
[... some code and initilisation here ...]
if(pthread_create(&scrollThread, NULL, mouseEvent2, NULL))
    goto _FAILURE_;
do {
    [...]
    while(g_wait);
}
[... some deinit ...]
_FAILURE_ :
pthread_join(scrollThread, NULL);
[... some other deinit ...]
return 0;
}
```

My problem is : when my main is waiting, my child thread is using at 100% 1 core processor, so which function can I use to pause the child thread with the main one?

I already consult [How to make main thread wait for all child threads finish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624545/how-to-make-main-thread-wait-for-all-child-threads-finish) but it didn't help me totally.

Comment: you can use a [brief sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684359/how-to-use-nanosleep-in-c-what-are-tim-tv-sec-and-tim-tv-nsec/7684399) to take the load off the cpu.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker how many time do you use to overload the cpu? I tested with 500 ms, my cpu is always at 25% using (with a quadcore)

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I added the follinwing lines in my program : `if(g_wait)
        {
            struct timespec waiting;
            waiting.tv_sec = 0;
            waiting.tv_nsec = 500000;
            nanosleep(&waiting, NULL);
        }`

Comment: you can use [yeild](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_yield.3.html) and i think g_wait should be an atomic

Comment: What does, "wait for the main program" mean? What is it that you want the main thread to _do_ before the child thread is allowed to stop waiting?

Comment: @Tyker `pthread_yield` didn't overload the processor

Comment: @jameslarge I want to be able to stop temporary the main thread, and this has as consequence of full utilisation of one processor because the child thread isn't waiting -> I would like to add some lines to let the cpu free of charge during this waiting

Comment: @damadam Why is the thread using 100% of the CPU anyway? What is it doing exactly? The code you've shown should block in `read` until there's data for it to read. If the thread is using 100% of the CPU when it has no work to do, that's likely just some bug in the thread's existing code. If it has nothing to do, what is it doing?

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to pause main thread until child thread signals about it ends, you can use mutexes to lock main thread:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "pthread.h"

/* I work on windows now, so i need windows sleep function to test example */
/* platform independed sleep function */
#ifdef _WIN32
# include "windows.h"
# define platform_sleep(ms) Sleep(ms)
#else
# include "unistd.h"
# define platform_sleep(s) sleep(s / 1000)
#endif


pthread_mutex_t mtx;


void *
child_func(void *arg)
{
    /* simulate some hard work */
    platform_sleep(3000); /* 3 secs */

    /* after this "hard work" we allow main thread to continue */
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
}



int
main()
{
    pthread_mutex_init(&mtx, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);

    pthread_t child;
    pthread_create(&child, NULL, child_func, NULL);

    /* mutex is already locked by main thread, so it waits */
    /* until child thread unlock it */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mtx);

    /* do work after child ends */
}
```

Comment: there is a `while` funtion in my child thread, so i'm not sure I will be able to use the `pthread_mutex_unlock` like that, and it's my user who decide to pause and resume the program, not an arbitrary value which define the waiting time

Comment: @damadam, pause is used just for example, of course u can use loops and other stuff.